# Adding API to Usage Plan using Serverless Framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

My `serverless.yaml` file is as follows:

```
service: aws-python

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: beta
  region: us-east-1

package:
  include:
    - deps
    - functions
    - lib

functions:
  hello:
    handler: functions/handler.function_handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: ta
          method: GET
      - http:
          path: ta
          method: POST
```

I want to add this API to a Usage Plan. How is this done?

Comment: If you're going to down vote a post you need to explain yourself.

Comment: Serverless doesn't support this by default, but you should be able to create a UsagePlan resource in your Serverless CloudFormation template, or script creation of the UsagePlan using the AWS CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the AWS CLI with the following command

```
aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id <PLAN_ID> --patch-operations op=add,path=/apiStages,value=<API_ID>:<API_STAGE>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, Serverless doesn't support this by default. You should look to add the appropriate resources to your CloudFormation template as a custom resource or create it using the AWS CLI or another SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are outdated.  Usage plans and API keys are now supported.  See here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api

Here is the example from the above document:

```
provider:
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - free:
          - myFreeKey
          - ${opt:stage}-myFreeKey
      - paid:
          - myPaidKey
          - ${opt:stage}-myPaidKey
    usagePlan:
      - free:
          quota:
            limit: 5000
            offset: 2
            period: MONTH
          throttle:
            burstLimit: 200
            rateLimit: 100
      - paid:
          quota:
            limit: 50000
            offset: 1
            period: MONTH
          throttle:
            burstLimit: 2000
            rateLimit: 1000
```

Comment: How Do i use usagePlan with Http Api?